# R: Increase space between multiple boxplots to avoid omitted x axis labels

Tags: r

Let's say I generate 5 sets of random data and want to visualize them using boxplots and save those to a file "boxplots.png". Using the code

```
    png("boxplots.png")
    data <- matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
    boxplot(data, names = c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"))
    dev.off()
```

there are 5 boxplots created as desired in "boxplots.png", however the names for the second ("Name2") and the fourth ("Name4") boxplot are omitted. Even changing the window of my png-view makes no difference. How can I avoid this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: increase the width of your plot / graphics window or decrease the size of your labels

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it made me aware that there is some more information needed to describe my problem, see my edit.

Comment: `png` has a width parameter, which you can use to make the plot wider. You can also rotate labels with `las` parameter. `boxwex` , `cex.axis` etc.. try a few to see what works for you

Comment: You could also have the labels written at an angle. Try text with srt = .45 , for example.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions - all your approaches worked and helped me! In the end, increasing the width of png happened to suit best for my particular setting - just to have this mentioned for completeness. Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your offered code does not produce an overlap in my setting, but that point is relatively moot: you want a way to allow more space between words.
One (brute-force-ish) way to fix the symptom is to alternate putting them on separate lines:

```
set.seed(42)
data <- matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
nms <- c("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5")
oddnums <- which(seq_along(nms) %% 2 == 0)
evennums <- which(seq_along(nms) %% 2 == 1)
```

(There's got to be a better way to do that, but it works.)

From here:

```
png("boxplot.png", height = 240)
boxplot(data, names = FALSE)
mtext(nms[oddnums], side = 1, line = 2, at = oddnums)
mtext(nms[evennums], side = 1, line = 1, at = evennums)
dev.off()
```

[image]

(The use of `png` is not important here, I just used it because of your edit.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - that's a nice/easy solution that I will keep in mind! Just for completion: the suggestion by user20650 using the width parameter happen to provide a nice solution as well where each label is "in one line" but the space between the boxes is increased.